# wrong font when print excel sheet from instance?

Tags: excel, vba, asp-classic

Im trying to open an excelsheet by using traditionell ASP. What i do is that i creating an instance of an excel object by using
Set excelApp = server.createobject("excel.application")

I then manage to open a worksheet and print it, only problem is that the fonts used in the worksheet doesnt match up when sheet is printed, what i mean is that the font selected in the sheet isn't the one when sheet is printed, i dont know wich font it is on the paper when printed in the way descripbed above.. 
If i physical open the worksheet by interaction and print it all fonts are as the should, but when open by asp script and print it its another font?

Does anyone now what happens when open excelsheet by instans, what kind of user is that run the application, does this in anyway effects the font selected for worksheet?+

Best regards..

Comment: What do you mean "the fonts don't match up?" Can you be more specific? Please edit your question.

Comment: @Joel Spolsky I tried to explane it a little bit better

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you have IIS set up and under what user account IIS is creating the Excel application object. Sometimes it's as simple as the IIS account (which might be IUSR_*machinename*) but sometimes it's based on all kinds of convoluted App Pool stuff that I don't even pretend to understand.

Microsoft has sample [VBA code which gets the current user's identity](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/161394). You could try running this from Excel as a user and Excel as an object and see what's going on.

Comment: yee i hade alot of problem with rights and witch user to run dcom object (excel) etc.. That i solved and i also changed the IIS account so that all pages are executed as admin user, same user as i log on with.. But it should work sp that the user that is selected in IIS is the one executing object? I'm gona try the example you gave me.. Thanks.